# Powerapps Explorer Dialogue to allow file selection

Tags: powerapps

I am trying to do what I would have through was very basic functionality. I am trying to setup a button so a user can click it, an explorer dialogue will pop up and let them choose their file. I see no way to do this and have read multiple places that this is impossible. What is the point of allowing someone to upload a file if they cannot chose it. The longer goal is to pull a file and read it into a database.

I tried following the below example, however, I do not have many of steps and even then, you must hardcode the path to the file name or pull it from a text box. Both are useless I need the user to select the file off their computer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this using the Attachments control inside of a Form! You can connect the form to your database and use this to attach one uploaded file.

Here is more info: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-attachments

And here is a good video that shows an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_946zp7SVjY

I hope this helps!